# Confusion matrix get value error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, valueerror

I am trying to create a confusion matrix with sci-kit learn for epileptic data set from
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Epileptic+Seizure+Recognition

after preparation, doing cross validation and modeling i got the result as follow (i tagged the screenshot):

[image]

now when i want to get confusion matrix i get this error:

```
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    conf = confusion_matrix(pred["y"], pred["PredictedLabel"])
    print(conf)
```

[image]

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case disagreement in the types of values in the dataframe  try converting the doubles (assuming they are doubles) to string. Try,

```
conf = confusion_matrix(pred["y"].values.astype(int).astype(str), pred["PredictedLabel"].values)
conf = pd.DataFrame(conf)
```

And if you want the labels you can add them back,

```
my_columns = ["y", "PredictedLabel"]
conf.columns = my_columns
print(conf)
```

Comment: Great. If this satisfied you purpose then please accept the answer (checkbox next to my answer) to help me be better able to help others in the future. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert both predicted and true label to `str`:

```
conf = confusion_matrix(pred["y"].astype(str), pred["PredictedLabel"].astype(str))
```

Trying to recreate the similar issue, consider following case where predicted and true are different types:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

pred = pd.DataFrame()
pred["y"] = [1,2,3]
pred["PredictedLabel"] = ['1','2','3']
conf = confusion_matrix(pred["y"], pred["PredictedLabel"])
print(conf)
```

It will give error: `ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)`.

If you convert them both to `str` type (*you may use other as int or float as well where both has to be same though for predicted and true labels*):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

pred = pd.DataFrame()
pred["y"] = [1,2,3]
pred["PredictedLabel"] = ['1','2','3']
conf = confusion_matrix(pred["y"].astype(str), pred["PredictedLabel"].astype(str))
print(conf)
```

Result:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```